# Inout in swift and reference type

Tags: swift, reference, inout

I'm trying to understand the difference between value and reference type. And now I want to use function from the apple guide:

```
func swapTwoInts(_ a: inout Int, _ b: inout Int) {
  let temporaryA = a
  a = b
  b = temporaryA
}
```

and if I want to use this is function I will write this code

```
swapTwoInts{&firstIntStruct, &secondIntStruct}
```

I understand that we must put in this function reference type, but Int is a value type, therefore we use &.
In another hand, when I try change Int to my class in the swap function, I also must write & before instance of my class.

Why I must do it, if it is the reference already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose we wrote the hypothetical function you're talking about:

```
class C {}

func swapTwoC(_ lhs: C, rhs: C) {
    let originalLHS = lhs
    lhs = rhs
    rhs = originalLHS
}
```

The immediate problem is that `lhs` and `rhs` are immutable. To mutate them, we would need to make mutable copies:

```
func swapTwoC(_ lhs: C, rhs: C) {
    var lhs = lhs; var rhs = rhs
    let originalLHS = lhs
    lhs = rhs
    rhs = originalLHS
}
```

But now the problem is that we're mutating our copies, and not the original references our caller gave us.

More fundamentally, the issue is that when you pass a reference (to an instance of a class, which we call an object) to a function, the reference itself is copied (it behaves like a value type). If that function changes the value of the reference, it's only mutating it own local copy, as we saw.

When you have an `inout C`, and you pass in `&myObject`, what you're actually passing in is a *reference to your reference to `myObject`*. When the function arguments are copied, what's copied is this "ref to a ref". The function can then use that "ref to a ref" to assign a new value to the reference `myObject` the caller has

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! But to confirm, when I use structure (value type) I only pass reference type into swapTwoInts(&firstIntStruct, &secondIntStruct), not reference to reference. How it's work correct?

Comment: And you mean, that inout creates copies into the function?

Comment: @Wike Function arguments are always copied. Either a value (an instance of a struct/enum/tuple) is copied, or a reference is copied (that refers to an instance of a class). `&firstIntStruct` is a reference to `firstIntStruct`. That reference is copied, and `swapTwoInts` gets its own copy to play with. `swapTwoInts` can dereference that reference to gain access to the memory of `firstIntStruct` (the same memory the caller refers to as `firstIntStruct`)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to explain it with example. As @Alexander mentioned, for th function with `Int` as parameter:

> **1. Pass by value**
>
> It will mutate the copies, and not the original references of caller.
>
> More fundamentally, the issue is that when you pass a reference (to an instance of a class, which we call an object) to a function, the reference itself is copied (it behaves like a value type). If that function changes the value of the reference, it's only mutating it own local copy, as we saw.

[image]

You can see that

`func swapTwoInts(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) { }`

If has changed the values of **p and q**, where **self.x and self.y** are unchanged. As this function is passing the values of **x and y** not their reference.

> **2. Pass by reference:**

`func swapTwoInts(_ a: inout Int, _ b: inout Int) { }`

It passes the reference of **self.x and self.y** and that's why you don't have to mutate them again as you did by taking p and q in previous type. Because it will take mutating object with `var x` and `var y`.

You can see that, a and b have values of references in logs and changing **a and b** has changed the **self.x and self.y** as well because a and b has the same reference( address) of x and y.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So there a few lower level memory components that are at play to make full sense of this.

1) When you create a value or reference type you have a new variable on the stack. That variable is either the actual data in the case of a value type or a pointer to the data in the case of a reference type.

2) When you call a function, it creates a new part of the stack and it creates new variables on the stack (which are `let` instances in swift) that copy the variable passed in. So for value types it does a deep copy and for reference types it copies the pointer.

So what this means is that when you use `inout` you are saying, take the memory address of this variable and update the data it contains. So you can either give a value type new data or a reference type a new pointer address and it will change outside of the scope of the swap function. It makes it a `var` (the same one as what is passed in) instead of `let` like normal.